# log4j2 does not output log file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Good day,

I have a Spring boot app, and I plan to add logger on it.

The following is my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.7.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.23'
}
```

And the following is my content of log4j2.properties under src/main/resources/:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = file

appender.file.type=File
appender.file.name=LOGFILE
appender.file.append=true
appender.file.fileName=/home/meow/Workspace/tool/tool.log
appender.file.filePattern=tool%d{yyyyMMddHH}_%i.log.gz
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.file.filter.threshold.level = info

#Generic logging
rootLogger.level=LOGFILE
```

In my java file:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        LOGGER.error("test log");
        SpringApplication.run(ToolApplication.class, args);
        
    }
```

The file `tool.log` never exist in `/home/meow/Workspace/tool/`.

I only can see my "test log" in console.

May I know which steps I did wrong?